# Can I use `@Cacheable` in a Controller?

Tags: spring-boot, caching

I want to cache my database access but I have no Repositories. This is how I'm doing (please don't ask why. This is not the point here):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/database", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public List<User> testDatabaseCache( @RequestParam("username") String userName ) {

    Object[] params = new Object[] { userName };
    String sql = "select * from public.users where user_name = ?";
    List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new UserMapper() );

    log.info("Database hit: " + userName);

    return users;
}
```

So... since I have no repository to annotate as `cacheable`, what can I do?

Comment: Never mind.... Yes, I can. Actualy, I asked this question before the test. After annotate the `testDatabaseCache` endpoint method as `@Cacheable("users")` I hit the database just once ( the log can confirm this). Thanks guys.

Comment: So.... how long this cache will live? I mean.... if the data in database changes will I get the cached data forever?